# Timer not working properly in android

Tags: android, timer, schedule, android-timer

Any one give idea, Timer will be schedule based on duration array and if once complete duration array length again will be start from first. In this some loop working perfectly some times will be crash and through arrayoutofboundsexception. Any one cane Help Me???

```
int[] duration={10000,2000,8000};
int layoutIncrment=-1;
private void layoutRotate()
{  layoutIncrment++;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {   public void run()
        {
            if((duration.length-1) <= layoutIncrment)
                layoutIncrment=-1;

            layoutRotate();
            Log.i("Rotation",String.valueOf(layoutIncrment));
    }   },duration[layoutIncrment],100000);
}
```

Comment: May i know whats wrong with that line??

Comment: I got answer every looping do cancel Timer otherwise all timer is in alive stage.

Answer (score 0):

why dont u try like this. it will keep running in the while loop.. thats only u want. right?

```
    int n=1;

    while(n>0)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<duration.length;i++)
    {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
   //add ur code here
    }
    }, duration[i]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Its not working.This Example is looping continually. I want delay from one duration to another duration. Once length is completed after will be start from first Duration..

Comment: use handler instead then

Comment: If u put handler or Timer in for loop,  for loops in running continuously don't have delay between loop.

Comment: u mean u want delay for the each duration?? means for example duration one completed then u want some delay before start the next duration?